# How to Move Multiple VM's to Different datastore

Tags: migration, datastore, powershell-v3.0, powercli

I have tried and search multiple way to migrate VM's to different data store

`$existingds = Get-Content dummy path`

`$newds = Get-Content dummypath`

`Get-Datastore $existingds | Get-VM | Move-VM -DiskStorageFormat Thick -Datastore $newds –RunAsync`

But for some reason, it is not working, I'm getting this error: 
`Move-VM : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.DatastoreManagement.StorageResource' required by parameter 'Datastore'. Specified method is not 
supported.`

If I run the command `move-vm -vm vmname -datastore new datastore`, it works without issue but when I try to put into an array, it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

`-Datastore` requires a datastore object, but you are providing an array of strings.

This should work:

```
Get-Datastore $existingds | Get-VM | Move-VM -DiskStorageFormat Thick -Datastore (Get-Datastore $newds) –RunAsync
```